# What's the different between these two `type` define which have different generic place, and how to use them?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, parametric-polymorphism, metalanguage

I found 2 different `type` like:

1. `type Pair = <Head, Tail> (head: Head) => (tail: Tail) => {head: Head; tail: Tail;}`
2. `type Pair <Head, Tail> = (head: Head) => (tail: Tail) => {head: Head; tail: Tail;}`

The only diff is `<Head, Tail>`'s place.

They're both legal but different while be use.

Such as:

When I define a function `pair`, I can use the first `type` define like this:

```
type Pair = <Head, Tail> (head: Head) => (tail: Tail) => {head: Head; tail: Tail;} ;

const pair: Pair = <Head, Tail> (head: Head) => (tail: Tail) => ({head, tail}) ;
const result = pair (1) ("two") ;

console.log(result); // {head: 1, tail: "two"}
```

But when I want to use the second `type` define on `pair`, I can only write that:

```
type Pair <Head, Tail> = (head: Head) => (tail: Tail) => {head: Head; tail: Tail;} ;

const pair: Pair<number, string> = <Head, Tail> (head: Head) => (tail: Tail) => ({head, tail}) ;
const result = pair (1) ("two") ;

console.log(result); // {head: 1, tail: "two"}
```

But that should not called `pair`, we should call it `number_string_pair` at least, but this is not what I want.

Use TypeScript *v5.2.2*, [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBAUAbzUnSAuAnjMgAogCWATkgLxIA8AEhCACYA0SAKhQDYB8SABQALFqwBcSZmwCUtQULx8pPcr3k1BGMWykzWAbnwrufQwF8kh7Lls54Ae2BQ8SOFSlkqtBgc5qAsK6ktLimorK6qp8EcI64pxRvBbyNrhITi5ulNAArrxudB7UQgCM8kIARHgA7o5VafZIzVlQjrwQAHS8jgDmQrlQBXiyxgD040gJekhlSaY19VUWaFY2aKCQsAjIAEKYzYTESN7UTIlm6oJ0ouL64QrCyTHqcTOhBsYvV7yW1s1Ws5XO4KJQvGD6MA8mAAEYQSicVyUcjAPo3PyXQKKEIPORPJSmQJxIQfBbqVIAjJtHL5Qq+ErCCrCJYNJoZIEuDrdXoDIYjMZISbTXFzcm8KSslZrAGbcDQOCIJAAYUOGWOpDBmLYAT4GLuswMJJ+xKeHzxRhM0V+-3SdmpwLcJQhVAuOt+GLdHA9wXuYXxWmeRNiBLJVpSaSFU1qlGcfU5IP59OKWvKlSl7PtuDa3J6-UGdNGEymXVLMpsQA) is the test.

---

To be honest, I want to know **how can I use the second `type Pair` define to `pair`'s type sign**, but I can't find it, so I asked this question ...

And, I want to know what the first `type Pair` mean ... I know about what `type Fn <X, Y> = (x: X) => Y` mean, the `Fn<number, string>` will same as `(x: number) => string`, but if I defined `type Fn = <X, Y> (x: X) => Y`, I can't use it like `Fn<number, string>` ... so, **what's the use of the second `type Fn` or first `type Pair` and what's the meaning of them ?**

Comment: As far as i see second one is easier to use (code completion works better on it) and thats mostly it.

Comment: but i would use `type Pair <Head, Tail> = (head: Head) => (tail: Tail) => {head: Head; tail: Tail;}` more, as it declares `Pair` tyle with two types provided on usage, looking like templated types from other languages (and ts should look like c# a bit). Also this one requires the types provided to be existing, not some generic names as even on 1st example you provided `Head/Tail` without proper typing

Comment: See the linked questions and answers for a description of the two different "flavors" of generic type parameter scopes.